# What function this PHP code do?

Tags: php, web

I am working in my first PHP project and I don't understand what does this piece of code does. May anyone help me please?

I don't work very well with php.

```
<?php

    $args = array(
        'post_type'   => 'manual-pdf',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'order'               => 'ASC',
        'orderby'             => 'title',
        'posts_per_page'         => -1,
        'meta_query'     => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',     
        // ['relation'] => 'OR', // use this for a different comparison
        array(
        'key' => 'wpcf-category',
        'value' => 2,
        'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
        'key' => 'wpcf-version',
        'value' => 1,
        'compare' => '='
        )

        ));

    query_posts($args);
    if ( have_posts() ) :

        while (have_posts()): the_post();

    ?>
        <a target="_blank" href="<?=$url = types_render_field("url", array('raw' => 'false'));?>"><? the_title(); ?></a><br><?=$descricao = types_render_field("description", array('raw' => 'false'));?><hr>
    <?
        endwhile;

    else :
    endif;
    wp_reset_query();

    ?>
```

Basically, this part made me confused mostly:

```
<a target="_blank" href="<?=$url = types_render_field("url", array('raw' => 'false'));?>"><? the_title(); ?></a><br><?=$descricao = types_render_field("description", array('raw' => 'false'));?><hr>
```

Comment: If you mean what <?= will do... it's a short syntax for echo. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking what a specific code does

Comment: It's just searching for posts based on the criteria in `$args` and outputting a list of links to each of them.